# How do I make packages available to the Scala REPL?

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

I'm trying to get familiar with Scala. I am using macOS.

I've installed scala using `brew install scala` which is hassle-free and once complete I can launch the scala REPL simply by issuing `scala` and I'm at the `scala>` prompt.
I now want to import some packages, so I try:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
```

and unsurprisingly it fails with

> error: object apache is not a member of package org

This makes sense, how would it know where to get that package from? Thing is, I don't know what I need to do to make that package available. Is there anything I can do from the command-line that would allow me to `import org.apache.spark.sql.Column`?

I have googled around a little but not found anything that explains in a jargon-free way. Complete Scala noob here so jargon-free responses would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two ways to start a REPL with dependencies that I'm aware of:

1. Use SBT to manage dependencies, use `console` to start a REPL with those dependencies
2. Use Ammonite REPL

---

You could create a separate directory with a `build.sbt` where you set

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.12"
```

and then copy the

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.3.0"
```

snippets from MavenCentral. Then you can run the REPL with `sbt console`. Note that this will create a `project` and `target` subdirectories, so it "leaves traces", you can't use it like the standalone `scala`-repl. You could also omit the `build.sbt`, and add the library-dependencies by typing them into the SBT-shell itself.

Alternatively you can just use [Ammonite REPL](http://ammonite.io/) that has been created exactly for that purpose.

Comment: Most useful answer (to me anyway). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `classpath` to make the lib available i.e. download the jar locally and use the command as follows (here I'm using Apache IO lib to move files from `scala` prompt )

```
C0:Desktop pvangala$ scala -cp /Users/pvangala/Downloads/commons-io-2.6/commons-io-2.6.jar
Welcome to Scala 2.12.5 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_161).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> import java.io.File
import java.io.File

scala> val src = new File("/Users/pvangala/Downloads/commons-io-2.6-bin.tar")
src: java.io.File = /Users/pvangala/Downloads/commons-io-2.6-bin.tar

scala> val dst =  new File("/Users/pvangala/Desktop")
dst: java.io.File = /Users/pvangala/Desktop

scala> org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.moveFileToDirectory(src, dst, true)
```

Comment: That doesn't help, where would I get the .jar from? Please understand that I'm a complete noob here.

Comment: Thank you Puneeth, very useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use spark stuff I'd recommend you use the spark-shell that comes with the spark-installation. I don't know macOS so I can't help you much with the install of Spark there.

For normal Scala I recommend ammonite http://ammonite.io/#Ammonite-REPL that has included syntax to allow to pull packages/dependencies.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to do this without a separate installation of Spark. I will take a look at ammonite.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use spark, you should use the `spark-shell` instead the scala REPL. It has almost the same behaviour but includes all the spark dependencies by default.

You should download spark binaries from [here](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html)

Then if you are using **Linux**, you should create the variable SPARK_HOME pointing to the downloaded folder and include its bin folder in PATH.

then you can start it in any console with the command spark-shell

In **Windows** i'm not sure, but i think that you should have a spark-shell.cmd file or something similar which you can use to start the spark-shell,

Answer (score 0):

I did the following in Windows:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('java -jar coursier fetch -p "com.lihaoyi::requests:0.2.0" "com.lihaoyi::upickle:0.7.5"') do set SCP=%%a

scala -nc -classpath %SCP% %1 %2 %3
```

Instead of the two libraries listed here you can use an unlimited number of other libraries you need. They must be available in maven central, though. The `%1` could be a scala script (".sc" extension). But you could leave it empty and the REPL will start with the libraries on the classpath.